# ExpressionEngine Wiki - Show categories in sidebar

Tags: wiki

Using the EE first party wiki application. I am trying to call all categories in the sidebar of the Wiki.

However the sidebar just prints out the tags. It seems you can only grab the categories in the categories template.

I am thinking that i am going to have to querie the DB directly to build the wiki menu system i want, but before i do has anybody else had any experience / thpoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spoke to Expressionengine support they have confirmed that The category tag is only going to be parsed on a category type url.

So a custom plugin is the way to proceed with this, using the categories function in mod.wiki.php. as inspiration.